Intercept all TRPC request
I'm using TRPC for a project:
https://trpc.io/docs/v9/vanilla
I'm looking to intercept all request to either run some analytics or do some adhoc pre request management.
Has anyone managed to do something similar? I've done this with Axios - hopefully there's something similar.

createTRPCClient takes a custom fetch as a parameter - can you just do it in there?

@AdamJenkins thanks! It seems to do the trick, though it feels a tad hacky
